# how to show all multi data array after loop and show all the data with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

heyy all i got some trouble with my code,
first i want tell my code after i find data like this:
1. api find

```
var Group        = require('../models/group/GroupAlm.js');
var fs          = require('fs');
module.exports = function(groupalm) {
groupalm.get('/groupalm/:nim', function(req, res){
  var getOne = req.params.nim;
    Group.find({ nim:getOne}).select('postings').exec(function(err, grooup){
      if (err){
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Not Found'});
      }else{
         res.json({ success:true, grooup:grooup});
      }
  })
});return groupalm;};
```

and 2. call to get api

```
var appFactory=angular.module('app.factory',[]);
   appFactory.factory('AllGrp',function($http){
      var allNotFactory = {};
          allNotFactory.getAllAlmGrp = function(nim) {
              return $http.get('/mod_mygroup/groupalm/' + nim);
          };
return allNotFactory;
});
```

3 is my controller

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope','AllGrp', function ($scope,AllGrp) {

function getGroupByPKNIMalm() {  
    var nim = 11037050017;
    AllGrp.getAllAlmGrp(nim).then(function(cek){
      if (cek.data.success){
          for (var i = 0; i < cek.data.grooup.length; i++){
              $scope.grp = cek.data.grooup[i].postings;
              console.log('data',$scope.grp);                                      
            }
     }else{ console.log('err');}
   });
}; getGroupByPKNIMalm();

}]);
```

**UPDATE TEXT HTML**
this ng-repeat for show data

```
<li class="list-group" role="presentation" ng-repeat="groups in grp | orderBy:'created_at':true ">
            <div data-role="container">
              <div data-role="content">
                <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left padding-right-10">
                      <i class="icon md-receipt bg-red-600 white icon-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h6 class="media-heading">{{groups.nim}}</h6>
                      <h6 class="media-meta">{{groups.post}}</h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
```

**/END UPDATE TEXT HTML/**

okey in step 1-3 is success to get data from api and thiss is my data after get/Find:

```
{
"success": true,
"grooup": [
  {
     "_id": "59eeb992a6ddc00f1037c1cf",
     "postings": [
          {
              "nim": 1137050017,
              "nama": "ADRIYANA PUTRA PRATAMA",
              "post": "hay salam kenal",
              "created_at": "2017-10-24T03:55:17.004Z"
          },
               {
                 "nim": 1111111,
                 "nama": "Fakih Nuzli",
                 "post": "hay salam kenal",
                 "created_at": "2017-10-24T04:01:14.954Z"
               }
      ]
 },
 {
   "_id": "59ef26cc0cfb2618d047cc6f",
   "postings": [
       {
           "nim": 1137050017,
           "nama": "ADRIYANA PUTRA PRATAMA",
           "post": "selata datang",
           "created_at": "2017-10-24T21:27:06.091Z"
       },
            {
               "nim": 1111111,
               "nama": "Fakih Nuzli",
               "post": "ya thanx",
               "created_at": "2017-10-24T21:27:29.384Z"
            },
       ]
 },
 {
     "_id": "59e53fcd1e85242ea417832e",
     "postings": [
          {
              "nim": 1111111,
              "nama": "Fakih Nuzli",
              "post": "hay",
              "created_at": "2017-10-24T11:19:44.318Z"
          }
      ],
}
]}
```

oke the problem is in the step 3, i loop data in controller, for show all data `postings`, look back again to step 3, there is a code for loop data like this code loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < cek.data.grooup.length; i++){
              $scope.grp = cek.data.grooup[i].postings;
              console.log('data',$scope.grp);                                      
            }
```

code up there successfuly to show data `postings` i look in `console.log`, but after i `ng-repeat="groups in grp"` and i try to show all `posting` `{{groups.nim}} and {{groups.post}}` **why he just show data posting in the last ID `59ef26cc0cfb2618d047cc6f`.**
**So how to show all data postings? after i loop and i get data from api `Group.find({nim})`.**
**thanks ;)**

Comment: you dont need for loop here, show the HTML code

Comment: ups sorry i forgot the html wait update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the arrays from each postings as follows,

```
 $scope.grp.push( ...$scope.result.grooup[i].postings);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.grp=[];
 $scope.result = {
"success": true,
"grooup": [
  {
    "_id": "59eeb992a6ddc00f1037c1cf",
    "postings": [
      {
        "nim": 1137050017,
        "nama": "ADRIYANA PUTRA PRATAMA",
        "post": "hay salam kenal",
        "created_at": "2017-10-24T03:55:17.004Z"
      },
      {
        "nim": 1111111,
        "nama": "Fakih Nuzli",
        "post": "hay salam kenal",
        "created_at": "2017-10-24T04:01:14.954Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "59ef26cc0cfb2618d047cc6f",
    "postings": [
      {
        "nim": 1137050017,
        "nama": "ADRIYANA PUTRA PRATAMA",
        "post": "selata datang",
        "created_at": "2017-10-24T21:27:06.091Z"
      },
      {
        "nim": 1111111,
        "nama": "Fakih Nuzli",
        "post": "ya thanx",
        "created_at": "2017-10-24T21:27:29.384Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "59e53fcd1e85242ea417832e",
    "postings": [
      {
        "nim": 1111111,
        "nama": "Fakih Nuzli",
        "post": "hay",
        "created_at": "2017-10-24T11:19:44.318Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]};
for (var i = 0; i <  $scope.result.grooup.length; i++){
   $scope.grp.push( ...$scope.result.grooup[i].postings);
                    
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li class="list-group" role="presentation" ng-repeat="groups in grp | orderBy:'created_at':true ">
  <h6 class="media-heading">{{groups.nim}}</h6>
  <h6 class="media-meta">{{groups.post}}</h6>
</li>           
</body>
```

Comment: wait wait wait if i push to array again i must loop $scope.grp again?

Comment: why do you want to push

Comment: sorry sorry, `$scope.grp.push( ...$scope.result.grooup[i].postings);` whether this should be in the push

Comment: yes it should, this is to merge the array, check the demo

Comment: so i must create like this `for(var i = 0; cek.data.grooup.length; i++){ $scope.grp = [];
$scope.real = cek.data.grooup[i].postings;
$scope.grp.push($scope.real);}`
like that??

Comment: i dont get what are you trying to achieve, did you check the demo